# Chrome won't resolve Vagrant/VirtualBox host?

Tags: google-chrome, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualhost

Due to `.dev` now being a gTLD and forcing redirects to https in Chrome, I set up a new development environment using PuPHPet with the domain `awesome.localhost` instead of the previous default `awesome.dev`.

Chrome doesn't resolve it at all and returns an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` message and no errors or information in console.

I can successfully ping the domain and the IP matches. It also works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Using the IP Address associated with the server in Chrome correctly returns the instructions page for adding the virtual hosts to the hosts file.

How can I resolve this? What could be causing this?

Chrome Version 63.0

Comment: I would suspect that Chrome bypasses DNS entirely for `.localhost` and just internally resolves it to 127.0.0.1 at all times. Try the `.test` TLD instead and see if that works.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88636/why-does-chrome-resolve-websitename-localhost-as-localhost appears to support my suspicions.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep, that was it. Changed it to 'test' and it worked.

Comment: @ceejayoz revisiting this, if you'd like to add/combine your comment(s) as an answer, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Chrome bypasses DNS entirely for `.localhost` domains and just internally resolves it to `127.0.0.1` at all times.

[RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) reserves the `.test`, `.localhost`, `.example`, and `.invalid` TLDs. I'd use `.test` for these sorts of internal host names.

Per the RFC:

> The domain "localhost." and any names falling within ".localhost." are special in the following ways:

> 1. Users are free to use localhost names as they would any other
>    domain names.  **Users may assume that IPv4 and IPv6 address
>    queries for localhost names will always resolve to the respective
>    IP loopback address.**

> 2. **Application software MAY recognize localhost names as special**, or
>    MAY pass them to name resolution APIs as they would for other
>    domain names.

> 3. Name resolution APIs and libraries SHOULD recognize localhost
>    names as special and **SHOULD always return the IP loopback address
>    for address queries** and negative responses for all other query
>    types.  Name resolution APIs SHOULD NOT send queries for
>    localhost names to their configured caching DNS server(s).

> 4. ...